# Providing directly viewable links to specific PDF pages in various TeX manuals

Tags: discussion

Many questions on the site ask for explanations of specific commands, 
for TeX/LaTeX/Engine Foo. The informations is often directly available
in one of canonical books like "TeX by Topic", "TeX for the Impatient", and of course "The TeXBook". At least some of these are freely and legally available 
as PDFs (assume for the moment that distribution issues were suitably settled).

It is technically quite simple to drop these PDFs on a website and provide
an in-browser viewer for displaying them, also allowing anyone
to link directly to a specific page of any hosted book. There may be
existing services (Scribd, once upon a time?) to do this, and if not,
Setting this up on github pages for example can be done with a couple of hours work. Knowing that the urls will work "forever", participants on the site could provide a directly viewable link to a precise location in a specific resource in comments and answers.

As a concrete **example** of how this could work, here is a [link](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html#page=4) to the tech demo for the [PDF.js project][1] from Mozilla, an in-browser PDF viewer, displaying a CS paper on javascript engine tech.

Implementation is easy, hosting is not a problem, assuming legal permission is obtainable or available, if there's no actual hinderance to putting this
in place, would it be useful or useless? is it a good idea? would it have negative side-effects on answer quality?

Comment: What's wrong with http://texdoc.net? Covers not only [_TeX by Topic_](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) and [_TeX for the Impatient_](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/impatient/book.pdf) but also all of the packages in TeX Live.

Comment: I haven't used it before. The search brings up nothing when you plug in `\parfillskip` for example, and the 'view' button simply links to the pdf for download. That's not quite what I was suggesting. Still useful, though.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186676/latex-command-examples-lookup-reference-from-the-command-line/197125#197125

Comment: You can use `texdoc` locally, too, of course: `texdoc texbytopic` or `texdoc impatient`, `texdoc source2e`, etc.

Comment: Handy, but asking users to (use linux) and edit their `.bashrc` is less convenient then a providing a direct link to a viewable page.

Comment: @JaredKulik Where's the need to use Linux/edit `.bashrc` files? `texdoc` works cross-platform, and not only with TeX Live: fine in MiKTeX too.

Comment: That was meant in response to the link andrew provided. I still think clicking a link is friendlier then switching out to a shell, typing a command with the right bookname and navigating to the page. By curious coincidence, my texlive install also doesn't have docs installed.

Comment: I just realized modern browsers show pdfs in the browser by default,  mine has it disabled by choice. Fo most users, It's true then that jumping to a page is a non-issue and a texdoc link is good enough.

Comment: @JaredKulik Perhaps a self answer based on your edit (if that works as a solution for you).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125632/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-bookmark-within-a-pdf-using-url-parameters

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As noted in the comments, **texdoc already provides this**—as long as your
browser is configured to view pdf file in the browser because, at least in firefox, appending `#page=123` to the texdoc package url is sufficient to have the requested page opened directly. Examples:

- `\looseness` [explanation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic#page=288) on Page 288 of `TeX By Topic`.
- [`Line breaking parameters`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/impatient#page=143) in `TeX for the impatient`.

**Edit:**
texdoc links (it seems) always point to the latest version, so absolute references to page number can break when manuals get revised.

**Edit:**
@thewaywewalk points out that it's possible to link directly to a **named destination** in the pdf by appending `#nameddest=<name>` to the url. Google turned up this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427302) and this [Adobe guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) on url parameters for pdf links.

- Section 7.1 of the `beamer` manual: [Link](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/beameruserguide.pdf#nameddest=subsection.7.1)

How are the named destinations created in the first place? `hyperref` creates them for use with internal hyperlinks (see [section 3.2](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref#nameddest=subsection.3.2) of the manual), naming each one using its own convention. By using the `nameddest` url parameter, you can link directly to any locations hyperref creates a named destination for, including section, subsection, figure, table, footnote, etc'.

**Edit:**
Here's a quick python script for listing all named destinations in a given PDF file (`pip install PyPDF2`):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Invoke from shell as `$ script.py foo.pdf`

import sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

pdf = PdfFileReader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
x=pdf.getNamedDestinations()
for n in sorted(x.keys(),key=lambda x:x.rsplit('.',1)[0]):
    print(n)
```

Comment: I didn't know it. I'll use in future answers. Thank you for sharing it.

Comment: @JaredKulik Regarding the breaking of page references. It maybe would work longer if not the pages, but the section directly is linked: e.g. Fontspec section 7.1: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#subsection.7.1

Comment: `#page=123` also works in Chromium (and thus, probably, Chrome).